# Determinant of transition matrix between subframes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have two frames (basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$) $F_1=\{\mathbf{e}_1,...,\mathbf{e}_n\}$ and $F_2=\{\mathbf{b}_1,...,\mathbf{b}_n\}$ and I know that the transition matrix between them:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\mathbf{b}_1=a_{11}\mathbf{e}_1+...+a_{1n}\mathbf{e}_n \\
...\\
\mathbf{b}_n=a_{n1}\mathbf{e}_1+...+a_{nn}\mathbf{e}_n
\end{matrix}\right.\iff A=\left(\begin{matrix}a_{11} & ...&a_{1n}\\
...&...&...\\
a_{n1} & ...&a_{nn}\end{matrix}\right)$$

has a positive determinant.
Then I also know that the first $k$ vectors $\{\mathbf{e}_1,...,\mathbf{e}_k\}$ and $\{\mathbf{b}_1,...,\mathbf{b}_k\}$ generates the same subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Can I say that also the determinant of $\left(\begin{matrix}a_{11} & ...&a_{1k}\\
...&...&...\\
a_{k1} & ...&a_{kk}\end{matrix}\right)$ has positive sign? If yes, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the case
$$A=\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&-1}?$$

Comment: @Angina Seng
Ok, I understood. Thank you.